# Parse.com Javascript Query to add only fields that are not already in Object Class (DB)

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, sdk

I am attempting to insert only objects that are not already in the object class. I have been stuck on this for the past 3 weeks, tried several different logic. Short of using MYSQL/SQL DB to store my items. I am running out of ideas.
Any and all suggestions will be appreciated. Thank you all.
I need conditional logic / for every IDField that already exists do not add it to the object class.
The code below is in a loop.
Here is my code:

```
var idField = $(this).text(); 
    var getFeed = Parse.Object.extend("Feed");
    var query = new Parse.Query(getFeed);
    query.equalTo("ID", idField);
    query.exists('ID');
    query.find({
    success: function(results){
    for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
    var object = results[i];
    console.log(object.id + ' - ' + object.get('ID'));
    testObject.save ({ID: json.ID}), {success: function(object) {alert("yay!!");}}
    testObject.save ({Date: json.Date}), {success: function(object){alert("yay!!");}}
    }   
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't really tell what exactly you're trying to do from your given code.  Where does testObject come?

You shouldn't be saving testObject twice.  The second one probably isn't even going through, because saves get called asynchronously, and you can only have one request / object, and Parse doesn't kick back any errors saying that it isn't performing the request, so you'll end up only doing the first save rather than both.

I'd also look into using Promises.  They make code a lot cleaner, and easier to handle all this asynchronous stuff, ensuring required stuff finishes before the code moves on.

Now, to actually help with your issue, it looks to me like you need to do use the doesNotMatchKeyInQuery method of the Parse.Query class found [here.](https://parse.com/docs/js/api/symbols/Parse.Query.html#doesNotMatchKeyInQuery)  Since I can't tell what you're actually trying to do with this based on your quest, I can't really give a specific example of how you'd use it.  You may actually want to use doesNotMatchKey, rather than doesNotMatchKeyInQuery, depending on your use case.